# What's the meaning/use of ?mt=8 and ?mt=12 in iTunes Preview and Mac App Store Preview URLs?

Tags: mac-appstore, ios-appstore

### Examples

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wuala/id417749289?mt=8&ls=1
http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/wuala/id417749289?mt=8
http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/visualdiffer/id412386481?mt=12&ls=1
http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/visualdiffer/id412386481?mt=12

#### Friendlier URLs

I dislike the effect of `ls=1` (launch App Store.app or iTunes.app) so I never share URLs in that format – I habitually remove that part of the URL.

I also habitually remove parts such as `?mt=8` and `?mt=12` – they seem superfluous. So for example:

- http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/wuala/id417749289
- http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/visualdiffer/id412386481

## Questions

Does either `?mt=8` or `?mt=12` add value to the end user?

If not to the end user, how do those things add value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MT stands for *media type*.  You can find known values in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781427/what-is-mt-8-in-itunes-links-for-the-appstore#answer-6774015) to similar question.

Because there’s usually an ID in URL, it may seem odd, but according to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862095/1254808) to that same question, the `mt` query parameter helps the operating system to launch the right store in the right app.  For example on iOS, you may see sometimes that links open the iTunes app first and then the iBookstore in the iBooks app.  Other times, the iBookstore is opened right away.  That is why `mt` should be part of iTunes and why you should probably use [iTunes Link Maker](http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker/).

Comment: There's an annoyance with iTunes Link Maker: its URLs for Mac apps differ from the URLs that are seen when links are  followed … but I blame these discrepancies on Apple. This is a great answer.

Answer (score 5):

mt - media type

mt-8 = mobile development software

mt-12 = desktop apps

```
1   Music
2   Podcasts
3   Audiobooks
4   TV Shows
5   Music Videos
6   Movies
7   iPod Games
8   Mobile Software Applications
9   Ringtones
10  iTunes U
11  E-Books
12  Desktop Apps
```